# elasticsearch search with multiple context values does not return expected results

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, opensearch

I use AWS openSEarch to store locations (cities, provinces, stations, etc...) and I query it from my nodejs app.
this is the body settings of the index

```
 settings: {
  analysis: {
    filter: {
      autocomplete_filter: {
        type: 'edge_ngram',
        min_gram: 2,
        max_gram: 20,
      },
      shingle_filter: {
        type: 'shingle',
        max_shingle_size: 3,
      },
    },
    analyzer: {
      autocomplete: {
        type: 'custom',
        tokenizer: 'standard',
        filter: ['lowercase', 'shingle_filter', 'asciifolding'],
      },
    },
  },
},
```

and this is the mapping object:

```
 properties: {
  id: { type: 'text' },
  city: { type: 'text' },
  station: { type: 'text' },
  resource: { type: 'text' },
  pointsOfInterest: { type: 'text' },
  name: { type: 'text' },
  country: { type: 'text' },
  countryCode: { type: 'text' },
  countrySlug: { type: 'text' },
  stationSlug: { type: 'text' },
  citySlug: { type: 'text' },
  timezone: { type: 'text' },
  name_suggest: {
    type: 'completion',
    analyzer: 'autocomplete',
    search_analyzer: 'standard',
    contexts: [
      {
        name: 'location_type',
        type: 'category',
      },
    ],
  },
},
```

you can see I use a `location_type` context which might get one of these values : `'city', 'pointOfInterest', 'province', 'zone'`

when I run the following query on the index:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
   "suggest": {
      "results": {
        "text": "hinton",
        "completion": {
          "field": "name_suggest",
          "fuzzy": {
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          },
          "contexts": {
           "location_type": ["city", "pointOfInterest"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I expect it to return also this document:
[image]

but it doesn't return the expected result.

if I run the exact same query but with only

```
"contexts": {
    "location_type": ["city"] // without "pointOfInterest"
 }
```

it will work and return the document.

I was reading that the context filter should behave like there's an `OR` operation in case more than one context name is provided.
What am I missing?